# Why am I getting include() and require() errors from one directory of my site and not another?

Tags: php, wordpress, include

Total newbie here, so take it as you will...

I'm doing a site upgrade right now, and everything works fine except...

I have a WordPress installation in a subdirectory, and now that I've brought the main site live, I'm getting

`include(/settings.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

and

`include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/settings.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:')`

on includes from within the subdirectory. I've played with setting different `include_path` settings, I know for sure the files are there (they are being included with no problems from the root directory), and I'm changed no permissions or anything during the rollout of the site.

Please let me know if this question is improper, or misplaced, or too vague, or what have you - first post after months of googling and lurking.

thanks in advance!

Comment: FWIW, the glaringly obvious yet momentarily, cunningly elusive answer was that the WordPress installation in its great wisdom sets the root directory of its files to its own root directory, so attempting to change that would fix this wee problem, but probably totally trash anything WP would try to do on my site. Dealing with it on a case by case basis, forcing include to hop up a step to root with ../

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely using php in a chrooted environment, so the root path of the server doesnt match that of the script.

Regarding the variables scope issue, could you post some sample code?

Comment: The variables scope issue is a non-issue. While I'd love to spend the time figuring out why it happened, it's really part of the vestiges of testing the main site out in a **beta** subdirectory, and can be removed now that I've migrated to root for the site. Cruft, begone!

For posterity, I include these two files in **index.php**, in this order: **header.php**, and **trace.php**. **header.php** defines `$linkHome`, **trace.php** references it, but throws `Undefined variable: linkHome in....trace.php`

Comment: Cool. If you need help with the scope issues later on, i'd recommend posting another question with sample code. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

"/settings.php" points to the root of your server. It should be "settings.php" if it is on the same path  and it should be in quotes.

Cheers

Comment: it is in the server root, and the error strips the quotes from it.
the include code is `include( "/settings.php" );`

Comment: Oh ok. Have you tried changing permissions on it? Run chmod 755 /settings.php from thr console

Comment: good idea, but ... didn't work. same error. the files include fine when I include them from a file in the root directory, but not from this subdirectory

Comment: Can you try this? die( file_get_contents( "/settings.php" ) );  it should give you the contents of the file.

Comment: Im guessing you might be running php chrooted, which means it treats / as a directory that is not really your server's root. You need to find out if thats the case

Comment: hey, this is getting to the ... root of it. sorry.
i'm new enough at all this that I don't know exactly how it would be chrooted, or how to fix it, but you're right - something in the WP configuration has set the root to be a directory one level down from root, so when I change the include to `include( '../settings.php' );` it gets the file.
now i have another problem - a variable i've defined in the file that includes is unavailable to the included file, which is something I've never seen before...
if you put your comment re: chroot as a answer, I'll check it. That's how this works, yes?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` to your wp-config.php file and report back with more information. Make sure to undo this any you grab the info for debugging as having this on a live site could be a security risk. I just search my whole WP directory for `include( "/settings.php" );` and could not find anything, which makes me think that it make be an issue with a plugin, theme, or other custom code. You could troubleshoot this by disabling all of your plugins, seeing if the site works again, and then painstakingly enabling your plugins individually until you find the culprit.

Does the error message you get point to a specific file and line number? That can help debug the problem.

Comment: oh, it points at exactly the lines in the files that are offending. it's definitely custom code of mine - it's part of how i integrate the blog code with the main code for my site. instead of copying the files that compose the shell for my main site, I include them from the wordpress files. as **JuanD** pointed out, in this part of my site (the WordPress subfolders), the root is not the root, and that's probably set somewhere deep in WP's config files.

Comment: I hope you get everything worked out! I thought that you didn't know where it was coming from, but, unfortunately, you do know where it's coming from and don't know how to fix it...that's the worst. Best luck.